# Spark query appends keyspace to the spark temp table

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I have a cassandraSQLContext where I do this:

```
cassandraSqlContext.setKeyspace("test");
```

Because if I don't, it complains about me setting up the default keyspace.

Now when I run this piece of code:

```
      def insertIntoCassandra(siteMetaData: MetaData, dataFrame: DataFrame): Unit ={
        System.out.println(dataFrame.show())
        val tableName = siteMetaData.getTableName.toLowerCase()
    dataFrame.registerTempTable("spark_"+ tableName)
    System.out.println("Registered the spark table to spark_" + tableName)

    val columns = columnMap.get(siteMetaData.getTableName)
      val query = cassandraQueryBuilder.buildInsertQuery("test", tableName, columns)
      System.out.println("Query: " + query);
    cassandraSqlContext.sql(query)
      System.out.println("Query executed")
  }
```

It gives me this error log:

```
Registered the spark table to spark_test
Query: INSERT INTO TABLE test.tablename SELECT **the columns here** FROM spark_tablename
17/02/28 04:15:53 ERROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1488255351000 ms.0
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Couldn't find test.tablename or any similarly named keyspace and table pairs
```

What I don't understand is why isnt cassandraSQLContext executing the printed out query, why does it append the keyspace to the spark temptable.

```
public String buildInsertQuery(String activeReplicaKeySpace, String tableName, String columns){
    String sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE " + activeReplicaKeySpace + "." + tableName +
        " SELECT " + columns + " FROM spark_" + tableName;
    return sql;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was I was using two different instances of cassandraSQLContext.In one of the methods, I was instantiating a new cassandraSQLContext which was conflicting with the cassandraSQLContext being passed to insertIntoCassandra method.